# Derivative of matrix term wrt to matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Assume we got matrices $X_{n\times n}$, $A_{n\times n}$ and $\Delta_{n\times n}$. The relation between these are as $X=A+\Delta$. Then how can one calculat the following derivative? Are there any assumptions for it?
$$\frac{d(I-A)^{-1}}{dX}=\frac{d(I-X+\Delta)^{-1}}{dX}\,.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$(I-A)^{-1}(I-A)=I$$
So, by the [Product Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) we have
$$\frac{d(I-A)^{-1}}{dX}(I-A)+(I-A)^{-1}\frac{d(I-A)}{dX}=0$$
that is
$$\frac{d(I-A)^{-1}}{dX}=-(I-A)^{-1}\frac{d(I-A)}{dX}(I-A)^{-1},$$
using (and assuming that delta does not depends on $X$)
$$\frac{d(I-X+\Delta)}{dX}=-I$$
we got
$$\frac{d(I-A)^{-1}}{dX}=-(I-A)^{-1}(-I)(I-A)^{-1}.$$

Comment: Does this mean that $\frac{d(I-A)^{-1}I(I-A)^{-1}}{dX}=(I-A)^{-1}I(I-A)^{-1}I(I-A)^{-1}$? (taking the second order derivative)

Comment: The right calculation gives $-(I-A)^{-1}(-I)(I-A)^{-1}(I-A)^{-1}-(I-A)^{-1}(I-A)^{-1}(-I)(I-A)^{-1}$. Where the product rule was used.

Comment: Aren't you missing $I$ in both of the terms? The term we want to take the derivative has $I$ itself as $(I-A)^{-1}I(I-A)^{-1}$ so shouldn't it show up in the product rule as well?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3474489/power-series-expansion-of-perturbed-matrix-inverse might be helpful. For the second derivative, it is the first derivative to the power two, right multiplied by the desired term.

Comment: Note that $=-(I-A)^{-1}(-I)(I-A)^{-1}=(I-A)^{-1}(I-A)^{-1}$.

Comment: Hmm... so am I missing a 2 in my calculations? Cause the first and second term you wrote would add up then.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\e{{\varepsilon}}
\def\B{B^{-1}}
\def\Bij{B_{ij}}
\def\Xkl{X_{kl}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$Let $\,\e_k\in{\mathbb R}^n$ denote the standard basis vectors
and note that
$$\eqalign{
X &= \Xkl\LR{\e_k\e_l^T} \qiq \grad{X}{\Xkl} = \e_k\e_l^T \\ 
}$$
For typing convenience, define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
A &= X-\Delta
 &\qiq dA = dX \\
B &= \LR{I-A}^{-1}
 &\qiq d\B = -dA \\
}$$
Now differentiate the $B$ matrix, starting with the definition of the matrix inverse
$$\eqalign{
I &= B\B \\
0 &= dB\;\B + B\;d\B \\
dB &= -B\;d\B\;B \\
  &= +B\;dA\;B \\
  &= B\;dX\;B \\
\grad{B}{\Xkl} &= B\LR{\e_k\e_l^T}B \\
\grad{\Bij}{\Xkl} &= \e_i^T\LR{B\,\e_k\,\e_l^TB}\e_j
 \;=\; B_{ik}\,B_{lj} \\
}$$
Notice that the resulting gradient expression has **four** free indices, therefore it represents a 4th order tensor, not a matrix.

However, the component-wise gradient in the preceding line is a matrix.